# Для чего пишут во FROM несколько таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql

Объясните мне в чем смысл когда пишут в запросе `select * from table1, table2`? При этом для второй таблицы все равно же пишут условия связи с первой. Почему ее просто не приджойнить?  Это выглядит намного логичнее и понятнее. По моему во `from` всегда должна быть одна таблица, а остальные джойниться.

Comment: Если поля таблиц совпадают, то можно забрать данные одновременно с двух (данные просто пойдут ниже). Но это не прокатит для двух разных таблиц. Вроде бы так, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar чего? О_о Кажется вы с `UNION` путаете.

Comment: *По моему во from всегда должна быть одна таблица, а остальные джойниться.* Не, такое надо было умудриться придумать! JOIN - он не сам по себе, он есть составная часть FROM. И соответственно FROM включает в себя все JOIN.

Comment: В одной старючей статье пишут, что это просто плохая привычка https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins автор еще в 2009 году призывал явно писать join

Comment: @Akina Капитан Очевидность.

Comment: @mrEvgenX я так и подумал. То есть смысл то абсолютно тот же что у джойна, но менее прозрачно. Например мне непонятно такая запись будет работать как left join или как inner?

Comment: Согласно документации https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html - все-таки inner... так сделали, якобы, для преемтсвенности поколений что ли. *This is a conservative extension if each comma in a list of table_reference items is considered as equivalent to an inner join*

Comment: Вначале в sql вообще **не было слова join**. Эта операция (точнее inner join) всегда выполнялась именно в виде `from t1, t2 where ....`. Потом в язык решили добавить еще и [другие виды join](http://datareview.info/article/8-sposobov-obedineniya-join-tablic-v-sql-chast-1/). И вот новое поколение уже и не мыслит жизни без этого слова.

Comment: @mrEvgenX Обязательно следует упомянуть, что приоритет запятой ниже, чем приоритет любого JOIN. А то начинаются потом дурацкие вопросы типа "А почему column not found error?".

Answer (score 0):

Это называется неявное соединение. Просто допустимый вариант соединения. Когда я начал писать много запросов под oracle - переехал именно на такой вариант. По моему мнению данный способ удобней.
Например left join  с ограничением на 2-й таблице под oracle:

```
    select *
    from   table1,
           table2
    where  table1.id = table2.id(+)
    and     table2.col1(+) = 10;
```

Comment: Субъективщина. А я считаю что это нечитабельно. Вот вы говорите что под oracle это left join, а под mysql говорят это inner join. Вот и гадай так на кофейной гуще как оно будет работать... Опять же лишнее условие в where, которое бы органичнее смотрелось в on.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК *Вот вы говорите что под oracle это left join, а под mysql говорят это inner join.* Не понял - лучше переспроси... внешним в Оракле это соединение делает `(+)`, a вовсе даже не картезианское произведение с условием отбора.

Comment: @Akina я вообще не понял что ты написал)

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Если из текста запроса в ответе убрать указанные 3 символа - то из исходного запроса с LEFT JOIN получится запрос с INNER JOIN. Так понятнее? Причём, что примечательно, достаточно убрать любую группу из двух (логически, насчёт синтаксически - не уверен).

Comment: @Akina чуток понятнее, но синтаксис конечно вырвиглазный. Почему просто не написать джойн? В миллион раз понятнее.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Потому что эта конструкция была изобретена, когда надобность во внешнем связывании уже была, а слова JOIN в словаре SQL keywords ещё не было...

Comment: @Akina ну вот и правильно написали в комментах к посту что это bad practice. Устарело и не должно больше использоваться. Джойны наше все!